# Validação do Input , utilizando um checkbox

Tags: javascript, html5

```
                <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                        <label>CNPJ</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
              <span class="input-group-text">
                <input id="checkbox-cnpj" name="_check-cnpj" type="checkbox">
              </span>
                            </div>
                            <input id="input-cnpj" name="_cnpj" type="text" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

esse é o meu codigo, gostaria de validar da seguinte maneira -- se o checkbox estiver marcado o input estará disponivel, se estiver desmarcado o input estará bloqueado

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Esse método  verifica se o **checkbox** esta marcado ou não, sua ação reflete em habilitar e desabilitar a entrada do **input**.

```
document.getElementById("checkbox-cnpj").addEventListener("change", function(){

  document.getElementById("input-cnpj").disabled = !this.checked;

});
```

implementado o *listener* para o elemento de checkbox associando ao **ID** `"checkbox-cnpj"` ,O uso `"change"` informa que havera uma chamada sempre que o estado do checkbox for alterado

**"**   *addEventListener*  **"** muito mais flexível,  permitindo agregar múltiplos *event listeners* para um unico elemento (*compatível com vários navegadores*)

Ao implementar  **comparação unitária**, expressasse a mesma lógica do uso `if` e `else` mas de uma forma mais curta.

Há situações em que o uso `if` e `else` é mais indicado, depende da complexidade e no uso lógica

Comment: Eu ia usar esse código numa resposta mas você disse o que iria dizer. Veja se complementa sua resposta https://jsfiddle.net/96oLbqua/

Comment: sim é uma ótima complementação mas tem o fato de que a proposta foi **se o checkbox estiver marcado o input estará disponivel** seria ótimo uso do `DOMContentLoaded` ou o `load` e a diferença no uso para o `"input-cnpj").disabled` ja carregar desmarcado :).. deixei essa parte de fora usando o addEventListener

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="form-group mb-3">
    <label>CNPJ</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">
        <input id="checkbox-cnpj" onclick="checkboxFunction('checkbox-cnpj','input-cnpj')" name="_check-cnpj" type="checkbox">
        </span>
      </div>
      <input id="input-cnpj" name="_cnpj" type="text" class="form-control" disabled>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function checkboxFunction(checkbox_id, input_id) {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById(checkbox_id);
    var input = document.getElementById(input_id);

    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
      input.disabled=false;
    } else {
      input.disabled=true;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).